# MySQL Query: How many times has a candidate won an election?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a web app in PHP using mySQL that models an election.

I have three tables: Candidates, Elections, and Votes.  Votes contains CandidateID, ElectionID and Count, which is the number of times that the given candidate was voted for in the given Election.  Votes also contains TimeStamp which is the last time the row was modified which is used for breaking ties (the earlier vote wins).  A candidate may have run in multiple elections.  How do I find how many elections a given candidate has ever won?

All help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Votes` (
`ElectionID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`CandidateID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Count` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`stamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ElectionID`,`CandidateID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Votes` (`ElectionID`, `CandidateID`, `Count`, `stamp`) 
VALUES
(1, 1, 3, 1332897534),
(4, 1, 3, 1333149930),
(4, 4, 2, 1333149947),
(4, 5, 3, 1333149947),
(1, 4, 4, 1333153373);
```

Desired output: One row, with one column, being the number of wins for a certain candidate

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired output...

Comment: @Vutukuri Thanks for the interest.  Please see edits above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM Elections AS e
 INNER
  JOIN Votes AS v1 -- representing the candidate of interest
    ON v1.ElectionID = e.ID
   AND v1.CandidateID = ...
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN Votes AS v2 -- representing a candidate who beat the candidate of interest
    ON v2.ElectionID = e.ID
   AND (    v2.Count > v1.Count
         OR (     v2.Count = v1.Count
              AND v2.stamp < v1.stamp
            )
       )
 WHERE v2.ElectionID IS NULL -- meaning that no candidate beat the candidate of interest
;
```

(It's also possible to represent either or both of those joins with `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery; or the first join could be changed to `IN` with an uncorrelated subquery; but the above is the most likely to perform best, IMHO, and my experience on StackOverflow has been that people seem to like joins better than subqueries for some reason. If you'd prefer a subquery answer, let me know.)

Comment: +1  FWIW, I think this is an occasion where MySQL's tuple comparison support comes in handy.  The compound condition for victory (more votes *OR* (equal votes AND earlier timestamp)) could be expressed as `(-v2.Count, v2.stamp) < (-v1.Count, v1.stamp)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CandidateID, MAX(Count) FROM Votes GROUP BY ElectionID
```

should do the trick

Comment: This query gives me the number of votes for the winning candidate of each election.

Comment: Ah, i misunderstood. Almost there then. Maybe you could simple now use COUNT(CandidateID) / COUNT(DISTINCT CandidateId) - or if that doesnt work use something like 'SELECT COUNT(CandidateID) FROM Votes GROUP BY ElectionID HAVING max(Count)'; or use ORDER BY Count DESC to get only the highest. I don't have time testing it for you, so you might have to toy around a little. I hope you dont mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your query basically needs to return every election and WHO Won it.  Then apply that result to the specific candidate your are interested in finding out how many that person won out of all elections.  Ex: in the U.S. Republican Race, you have 4 candidates... 2 are really the only real considered by most regardless of party affiliation.  Each party runs their campaign in each state and they all have their respective votes tallied.  So, at the end of ex: 20 states, you will only have 21 winners, but who won how many.  Candidate "A" may win 10,  "B" wins 6, "C" wins 3 and "D" wins 2.  So if you wanted to know how many Candidate "B" won, your answer desired is 6... from my impression of your question.

This will give you all qualifying "First Place" elections for a given candidate.  If all you care about is  the HOW MANY, you can just change the Prequery.fields to COUNT(*).  If you want to get the candidate's name and the name/info of the election, you can add that as join conditions AFTER the PreQuery has been executed.

```
select 
      PreQuery.idVotes,
      PreQuery.CandidateID,
      PreQuery.ElectionID,
      PreQuery.Votes,
      PreQuery.LastEntry
   from
      ( select
              v.*,
              @WinRow := if( @LastElection = v.ElectionID, @WinRow +1, 1 ) as FinalPlace,
              @LastElection := v.ElectionID as ignoreMe
           from
              Votes v,
              ( select @WinRow := 0, @LastElection := 0 ) sqlvars
           order by
              v.ElectionID,
              v.Votes DESC,
              v.LastEntry ASC ) PreQuery
   where
          PreQuery.FinalPlace = 1
      AND PreQuery.CandidateID = CandidateIDYouAreInterestedIn
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is group the Votes rows by ElectionID, and order by Count descending, stamp ascending.  That will give you a result set of ordered Votes rows, with the "winners" of each election as the first row within each group.

Next, you want to select these first rows within each group and discard the rest (see here for how to do a Top-N query:  http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group).

Finally, you want to select count(*) from this result set where CandidateID = whatever candidate you're looking for.  Alternatively, you can group by CandidateID and leave out the where clause if you want the number of wins for all candidates instead of a specific one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I'm late to the party, but this is the first thing I though of:

1. First have one subquery to select the winning count for each unique electionid in Votes, call this table `wins`.
2. Then, join `wins` with Votes where electionid and count are equal.  Because there may be a tie, we also need to choose the Votes row with the lowest stamp, so we'll group by electionid and count but this time choose the minimum stamp.  We'll call this resulting table `wins_with_stamp`/`wws` for short.
3. Now, `wins_with_stamp` has all of the rows from Votes that are "winning" rows, so selecting how many a particular candidate won is just a matter of a `where candidateid = ?` clause.

   ```
   -- Returns how many Votes rows that is the winner of its election  
   -- and candidateid is the candidate in question
   select count(*)
   from Votes v2
   right join (
      -- Gets the earliest stamp for the votes with the winning count for each election
       select v.electionid, v.count, min(v.stamp) as minstamp
       from Votes v
       right join (
           -- Gets the winning count for each election
           select electionid, max(count) as max
           from Votes
           group by electionid
       ) wins on wins.max = v.count and wins.electionid = v.electionid
       group by electionid, count
   ) wws on wws.count = v2.count and wws.electionid = v2.electionid and wws.minstamp = v2.stamp
   where candidateid = [YOUR_CANDIDATEID]
   ```